# How to be an astronaut?

Tags: nasa, astronauts

I always wanted being an astronaut. I am now going to high school and want to major astronomy in university.

The problem is I live in South Korea, not US.

Can you guys tell me how a foreigner can be an astronaut at NASA and if astronomy is not that helpful, which is better?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_Astronaut_Program